# Why is my armature not showing in animation layout, but it shows in the default layout?

Tags: animation, 3d-view, armature

How can i solve the problem caused by switching from default layout to animation layout?

Here you can see my default screen, where the armature is showing along with the sculpture of a human body.

[image: Here you can see my default screen. Where the armature is showing and the sculpture of a human body.]

And Here you can see my animation layout, but the armature is not showing.

[image: Here you can see my animation layout, but the metaring is not showing, is there a setting I need to change to make it see able? if I try to unhide the pose mode, in the right side of my screen, blender tell me "not yet implemented" what do i have to do to solve this?]

Is there a setting I need to change to make it visible? if I try to unhide the pose mode, in the right side of my screen, blender tell me *not yet implemented* what do I have to do to solve this?

Comment: how can i sold the problem in switching from default mode to animation mode?

picture 1 here you can see my default screen. Where the metaring is showing and the sculpture of a human body.][1]][1]


picture 2Here you can see my animation layout, but the metaring is not showing, is there a setting I need to change to make it see able? if I try to unhide the pose mode, in the right side of my screen, blender tell me "not yet implemented" what do i have to do to solve this?

Comment: Do you mean the armature?

Comment: That is weird, what is you graphics card? Could you post your Blender file?

Comment: Check on the Object Data tab and see if "X-Ray" checked or unchecked -> https://www.blender.org/manual/en/_images/RiggingEditingObjectDataPropertyCxtDisplayPanel.jpg

Comment: Hi rowe welcome to Blender SE.  Could you post a .blend of this file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and link in this thread here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Rigify and haven't created the actual rig yet. Your Blender also looks strange as there are not Layers on the header for the 3d View. With your mouse cursor over the 3d view press the ` key (above Tab) to hide/show all layers. As this may also be the case.

Go to your user settings (ctrl+alt+u) and select the File tab. Then make sure Auto Run Python Scripts is check marked.
[image: User Preferences]

Comment: Only enable auto run pythons scripts if you are certain they are not malicious...if you enable this you should DEFINITELY set up the excluded paths to contain AT LEAST your downloads folder ; )

Answer (score 0):

Double-check which layer the armature is on, and ensure that that layer is enabled when moving over to the animation layout.

Also, in the first screenshot (Default Layout), it looks like you're currently in "Local View" (Numpad-/).